# stream dynamically generated content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, amazon-s3, streaming

I'm trying to use `send_data` to stream dynamically generated content. However, it looks like the send_data expects one complete chunk of data to send, because I'm getting a DoubleRenderError.
The example in `aws-s3` must be wrong?

```
object.value do |segment|
  send_data segment
end
```

This gets called each time a segment is received from s3, so it tries to call `send_data` multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Double render error occurs when in an action `render` is called two times since call `render` doesn't stop execution of the action. Try to show us the complete action code, possibly you have a `render` at the end of the action and another before it.

Comment: I think it was because `send_data` was called twice. `send_data` expects a complete buffer which it will send at once.